# Anchor doesn't work after merging two different PDF using iText

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

I have created two PDF reports using Jasper and merged those into a single PDF file. The first PDF report contains the Anchor link  and the second PDF report contains the Anchor target. After merging the two PDFs, the anchor does not work. How should I fix this?

part1.jrxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.1.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2016-01-03T23:14:55 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="part1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8d0dcb70-0391-45e2-9263-4ac8cfa5f0de">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="405" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="370" width="100" height="30" uuid="0f29cf02-60d5-43d7-b360-3254134a6f77"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Anchor Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["expert"]]></anchorNameExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

---

part2.jrxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.1.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2016-01-03T23:24:42 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="part2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3f401f6e-4962-4a54-9674-4b0c613f9e73">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="389" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                <reportElement x="430" y="350" width="100" height="30" uuid="53f9f5fa-df7a-4fa3-bc1d-57b8be0c130a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Anchor Target"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["./result.pdf"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["expert"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

---

Merged.pdf

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy;


public class MergePdf {

    public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String RESULT= "/home/expert/Desktop/result.pdf";
        String[] files = {"/home/expert/Desktop/part1.pdf", "/home/expert/Desktop/part2.pdf"};
        mergePDF(files,RESULT);
    }




    public static boolean mergePDF(String sourcefiles[],String targetfile){
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy;
        try {
            //copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(targetfile));
            copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(targetfile));

            document.open();
            PdfReader reader;
            int n;
            for (int i = 0; i < sourcefiles.length; i++) {
                reader = new PdfReader(sourcefiles[i]);
                n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                for (int page = 0; page < n; ) 
                    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                copy.freeReader(reader);
                reader.close();
            }
            document.close();
            System.out.println("INFO :: Merging Complete of temp files");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you provide some simple example for testing purpose (jrxml file example and java code)...?

Comment: How attached the source code?

Comment: You edit the question... (with code formatting), please try to keep it short just an simple example of what is happening... not irrelevant code... if you have trouble do your best when editing the question, I can help you out with formatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to merge the `JasperPrint` and then to export to pdf, using the `SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(List<JasperPrint>)` as exporter input

This will make the bookmarks and anchors work correctly

Example

```
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

JasperReport report1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("part1.jrxml");
JasperReport report2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("part2.jrxml");

//Get all the JasperPrint and add them to my list
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report1, paramMap);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint1);
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, paramMap);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint2);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList)); //Set as export input my list with JasperPrint s
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/BookmarkTest.pdf"));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Hello, The Anchor and Hyperlink is working in merged PDF, but tool tip on Link not working.

Comment: This is theoretically another question, but I will check how tool tip works and get back to you....

Comment: and I also want to know How to accept the answer of previous question

Comment: @AshutoshKumar Ok, I have checked tooltip there is no native support for generating tooltip with the JRPdfExport, the only solution seems to be overriding the setHyperlinkInfo and use annotation... However this is another question (not related to the merge of pdf), give me some time I will test it, in the meanwhile consider passing another question on how to generate tooltip in pdf...

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer, checking into how to generate both local anchor and tooltip, its not really straight forward.... ; )